# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'display' referenced before assignment in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in python, and was trying to create a basic GUI calculator using Tkinter module. My code gives me an error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'display' referenced before assignment even when I've assigned the value to the variable in the beginning of the code. Here is my code, any help will be appriciated.

```
display = ""
flag = 0

def set():
    display = display + str(a)
    if flag == 0:
        calc1 = float(display)
    elif flag == 1:
        calc2 = float(display[len(str(calc1)) - 1:END])
    label.config(text = display)
    print (calc1)
    print (calc2)
    print (display)

def set0():
    a=0
    set()

# similar functions for values 1-9

set0()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be here:

```
def set():
    display = display + str(a)
```

Since you didn't declare `display` to be global, this is a local variable.  It's uninitialized.  I'm not 100% certain, since you didn't include the full error message, but this line will certainly elicit a fatal error.

You can reference a global variable without the declaration, but you can't change its value.

Note: you also have a definition problem with `a` in the `set` function: there's no such variable here.